# Mapbox marker symbol color change

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am placing markers by pulling coordinates from a MSSQL database.

I would like to make the markers (circles) a different color (red [#ff0000] or blue [#0000FF] depending on another variable in the database, but all the markers are brown (see source, link below).

here is an example:

```
map.addSource("markers", {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                          "type": "Point",
                          "coordinates": [-98.00371, 38.65447]
                        },
            "properties": {
                            "description": "<strong>UTEP 5560</strong>
                             <p>Ellsworth Co., Kansas: 38.65447, -98.00371: : JOHNSON, JD</p>",
                            "marker-size": "small", 
                            "marker-color": "#0000ff", 
                            "marker-symbol": "circle"
                          }
},....
```

---

```
map.addLayer({
  "id": "markers",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "markers",
  "layout": {
  "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}-11",
  "icon-allow-overlap": true,
  "text-field": "{title}",
  "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
  "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
  "text-anchor": "top"
 }
});
```

The full source code can be viewed here:  http://webapps.fhsu.edu/ksfaunatest/account.aspx?o=33&t=75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the mapbox circle layer instead of marker layer, With that you can do data driven styling and give colors based on the 'mytype' property in the geojson

Below is the sample of the circle layer

```
    map.addLayer({
    'id': 'mapid',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': source,
    'paint': {
        'circle-radius': 2,
        'circle-color': {
            property: 'mytype', // geojson property based on which you want too change the color
            type: 'categorical',
            stops: [
                ['type1', '#fbb03b'],
                ['type2', '#223b53'],
                ['type3', '#e55e5e']
    }
});
```

Visit this link for a live [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above uses the categorical layer property where you can color your circles depending on e.g. the category by using different stops.

I guess you just want to use a color that you define in the geojson feature properties. Then you could use the layers identity property like this:

```js
 map.addLayer({
    id: 'layerId',
    source: 'sourceName',
    type: 'circle',
    paint: {
      'circle-radius': 2,
      'circle-color': {
        type: 'identity',
        property: 'marker-color',
      },
    },
  });
```

Also see: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#function-type

Comment: I've run into a similar problem, but I use pop-ups, if I change to a circle layer, can I still do popups on click?